# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=20; index=20?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, arraylist

it shows me this error when I enter in my listview over 20 "pieces", how can I do to avoid this?

```
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=20; index=20
>  at com.Amarildo.asd.List_View_Esercizi.getView(List_View_Esercizi.java:33)
```

the error is at this line

```
img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
```

appears only if I post in the listview more than 20 components

This is my adapter

```
public class List_View_Esercizi extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Activity context;
private String[] nome;
private Integer[] imageId;

public List_View_Esercizi(Activity context, String[] nome, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_view_esercizi, nome);
    this.context = context;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_esercizi, null, true);
    TextView txt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    txt.setText(nome[position]);
    img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: post other methods too

Comment: `nome` is bigger then `imageId`

Comment: thanks Blackbelt (i haven't noticed) how do I vote your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are providing the `nome` as dataset for your adapter that is bigger then `imageId`. Since the `getCount()` is based on nome, you will get getView called `nome.lenght - 1` times. When position exceed the value of `imageId.length - 1`, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutBoundException`

Answer (score 0):

index goes from 0 to length-1. Therefore you get the Exception when trying to access element[length].

Answer (score 0):

If you're unsure of the sizes of your array just add a simple check, so setting the text and/or image is skipped.

```
if (nome.lenght > position) {
    txt.setText(nome[position]);
}
if (imageId.lenght > position) {
    img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because one of your array is bigger in size than another ,

So I have a suggestion for you, If you have both of them same sized you should try to create a POJO class and make your ArrayAdapter use your POJO[] , that would reduce complexity and enhance readability and your code will be easy to debug also.

Njoy!